# Fill down text value in column where following cells are blank

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a dataframe and i'm trying to fill down the value in the 'Date' column (which is text),as follows:

The dataframe is generated using `dfs=pd.read_html(pageUrl,infer_types=False)` then `df=dfs[0]`

```
            Date     Time datetime  Year
    0               None     None  2007
    1     May 1     0:58     None  2007
    2               1:00     None  2007
    3               1:30     None  2007
    4               1:45     None  2007
    5               3:45     None  2007
    6               4:45     None  2007
    7               6:30     None  2007
    8               7:15     None  2007
    9               7:45     None  2007
```

`df.dtypes` shows;

```
    Date        object
    Time        object
    datetime    object
    Year         int64
    dtype: object
```

Firstly I tried filling on a per-row basis. Trying to shift back one row to get the previous value if the current 'Date' is empty:

```
    def fillDate(r):
        if r['Date']=="":
            p=r.shift(-1)
            r['Date']=p['Date']
        return r
```

then

```
    df.apply(fillDate,axis=1)
```

This populates the 'Date' column with the 'Time'.

So then I tried applying with axis=0 (per column basis) and modifying the function so it only applies this to the 'Date' column (I can't see how to apply this to just one column)

```
    def fillDate(r):
        if r.name=='Date':
            if r['Date']=="":
                p=r.shift(-1)
                r['Date']=p['Date']
        return r
```

then

```
    df.apply(fillDate,axis=0)
```

gives the error

```
    KeyError: ('Date', u'occurred at index Date')
```

The aim is to fill down the value in the 'Date' with the value from the previous cell when the 'Date' is blank.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
In [16]: df = pd.read_fwf(StringIO(data),widths=[5,12,8,8,6],header=0,names=['idx','date','time','datetime','year'])

# simulate what the OP actually has (though this doesn't happen upon read in)

In [30]: df['date'] = df['date'].fillna('')

In [31]: df
Out[31]: 
   idx   date  time datetime  year
0    0         None     None  2007
1    1  May 1  0:58     None  2007
2    2         1:00     None  2007
3    3         1:30     None  2007
4    4         1:45     None  2007
5    5         3:45     None  2007
6    6         4:45     None  2007
7    7         6:30     None  2007
8    8         7:15     None  2007
9    9         7:45     None  2007

In [32]: df.loc[df.date=='','date'] = np.nan

In [33]: df
Out[33]: 
   idx   date  time datetime  year
0    0    NaN  None     None  2007
1    1  May 1  0:58     None  2007
2    2    NaN  1:00     None  2007
3    3    NaN  1:30     None  2007
4    4    NaN  1:45     None  2007
5    5    NaN  3:45     None  2007
6    6    NaN  4:45     None  2007
7    7    NaN  6:30     None  2007
8    8    NaN  7:15     None  2007
9    9    NaN  7:45     None  2007

In [34]: df['date']  = df['date'].ffill()

In [35]: df
Out[35]: 
   idx   date  time datetime  year
0    0    NaN  None     None  2007
1    1  May 1  0:58     None  2007
2    2  May 1  1:00     None  2007
3    3  May 1  1:30     None  2007
4    4  May 1  1:45     None  2007
5    5  May 1  3:45     None  2007
6    6  May 1  4:45     None  2007
7    7  May 1  6:30     None  2007
8    8  May 1  7:15     None  2007
9    9  May 1  7:45     None  2007
```

Comment: That doesn't work because the empty 'Date' values are not 'NaN' they are empty strings. Also, ideally, I want to do this using `apply` as there are other things I want to do within that function which I removed to simplify this question.

Comment: easy enough to 'simulate' what you actually have, not sure how they got there as you didn't show how you generated this frame

Comment: then show what you actually want; this is the efficient way of doing it, apply is essentially a loop in python space

Comment: The frame was generated using `dfs=pd.read_html(pageUrl,infer_types=False)` - I had to disable infer_types as it caused some values to be omitted. Hence the blanks.

Comment: where was it causing the ommissions? e.g. what 'kind' of data (could be a bug there)

Comment: Thanks Jeff. That's just what I need. Re: disabling infer_types - I omitted extra columns from my example. These had varying figures in them, some in standard decimal form, others were things like 45K, 5M, 4.3B or 5.25%. As some of the numbers at the beginning of the data were numbers, it would seem the parser infers the columns are floats and discarded the following non-float items.

Comment: you can pass ``dtype = { column_name : str }`` (and specify multiple columns if you want to disable type inference

Answer (score 3):

If I am understanding the problem correctly, it should be as easy as,

```
df['Date'] = ['Date'].ffill(axis=0)
```

This will fill any missing values with the previously available value from the same column.

Here are some links that can be used to understand the method, including the documentation,
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html
https://www.studytonight.com/pandas/pandas-dataframe-ffill-method